# How to inherit state from multiple classes?

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns, composite

I have a composite like pattern in where there is different functionality for the roots of the trees, branches and leafs. The problem is that there is a shared state between both Root with Branch and Branch with Leaf. I'm searching for the cleanest solution which prevents code duplication.

[image: Diagram]

The functionality among root, branch and leaf all relate to the same set of methods (though leaf has different signatures).

- **Embeddable** interface implicates that the implementation has a parent and some mutable properties.
- **Composite** has *Embeddable* children and provides abstract functionality methods for which *Root* and *Branch* have their separate implementations.
- **Root** is the actual executor of most functionality.
- **Branch** will most often - but not always - pass information to its parent with modified parameters.
- **Leaf** can appear both on the root and branches and has fewer functionality methods with smaller method signatures. Will always pass its calls to its parent with extra parameters. It is stored explicitly in every *Composite* where it is created and loaded lazily.

### Shared state

- *Root* and *Branch*'s shared state is in this case solved by *Composite*.
- The *Embeddable* interface enforces that *Branch* and *Leaf* provide its behavior.

The problem the implementation is the same for *Branch* and *Leaf* and implementing it would cause duplicate code. It's impossible to make *Embeddable* an abstract class because *Branch* already extends *Composite*.

I'm searching for a pattern or general solution so that *Branch* can share state with *Embeddable* and *Composite* at the same time. Basically a multiple-inheritance workaround.

### Implementation

This design is in practice used to structure a 3D block environment. Root being infinite in space, branches are a subsection with an offset in the space of its parent and leaves represent 1 block relative to its parent offset. Some functionality for root and branch thus requires coordinates as parameters, whereas leaf won't require those, since it's already at 1 coordinate.

```
public abstract class Container{
    private List<Embeddable> children;
    private WeakHashMap<Integer, Leaf> leafs;

    public abstract boolean setBlock(short x, short y, short z, byte id, byte data, SetBlockStrategy setBlockStrategy);
    public abstract void tick();
    public abstract void activate(short x, short y, short z);

    protected final Leaf getLeaf(short x, short y, short z) { ... }

    protected void addChild(short x, short y, short z, Embeddable child) { ... }
}

public interface Embeddable {
    void setParent(Container parent, short x, short y, short z);
    void clearParent();
    Container getParent();
}

public class Root extends Composite {
    private RootSpecificObject rootSpecificParameter;

    public boolean setBlock(short x, short y, short z, byte id, byte data, SetBlockStrategy setBlockStrategy) {
        controller.doStuff();
    }

    public void tick() {
        controller.doStuff();
    }

    public void activate(short x, short y, short z) {
        controller.doStuff();
    }
}

public class Branch extends Composite implements Embeddable {
    private BranchSpecificObject branchSpecificParameter;

    // Duplicate code
    private short xOffset, yOffset, zOffset;
    private Container parent;

    public boolean setBlock(short x, short y, short z, byte id, byte data, SetBlockStrategy sbs) {
        parent.setBlock(x + xOffset, y + yOffset, z + zOffset, id, data, sbs);
    }

    public void tick() {
        controller.doStuff(xOffset, yOffset, zOffset, ...);
    }

    public void activate(short x, short y, short z) {
        parent.activate(x + xOffset, y + yOffset, z + zOffset);
    }

    // Duplicate Embeddable implementation
}

public class Leaf implements Embeddable {
    private byte id, data;
    // Duplicate code
    private short xOffset, yOffset, zOffset;
    private Container parent;

    public boolean setBlock(byte id, byte data, SetBlockStrategy sbs) {
        return parent.setBlock(xOffset, yOffset, zOffset, id, data, sbs);
    }
    public void activate(short x, short y, short z) {
        parent.activate(xOffset, yOffset, zOffset, id, data, sbs);
    }

    // Duplicate Embeddable implementation
}
```

Comment: By "parent functionality", you mean implement the methods?

Comment: Also, if this is anything like a Binary Tree, the Root and Leaf are simply considered a Node, and each Node has children references. If a Node has all null children references, then it is a leaf. Does that help?

Comment: Maybe you can make use of [java8's default method implementations on interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html). This can be used to avoid code redundancies, and provides solutions for situations where multiple inheritance is required. However, there are limitations such as AOP-like interception.

Comment: Java does not provide a mechanism for and does not allow multiple inheritance of state; but it does allow multiple inheritance of both implementation (with a set of rules to resolve namespace collisions) and type.  From your description, it does not appear that you have a problem of multiple inheritance of state.

Comment: I respectfully suggest that your object model domain may not be optimally designed in order to facilitate an elegant object-oriented solution for your problem domain.

Comment: It would be more clear if you would provide you code.

Comment: By the way, what you do is not composite pattern at all.

Comment: I added some code to clarify the implementation requirements. Parent functionality was referring to calling its parent with modified parameters.

There is already an interface to enforce the shared behavior for Embeddable, but it can't share its parameters. Default methods don't help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what exact code is duplicated, but the common way for such problem is to delegate state and behavior to another class.

Remember there's always a trade-off between readability and easiness to maintain such code. Think twice now that you really need to avoid code duplication.

Short example for your code

```
public class Branch extends Composite implements Embeddable {
    EmbeddableDelegate delegate;
}

public class Leaf implements Embeddable {
    EmbeddableDelegate delegate;
}

public class EmbeddableDelegate [implements Embeddable] {
    private short xOffset, yOffset, zOffset;
    private Container parent;
```